# Spring data JPA save method returns null

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save a new entity with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate from JUnit test case. The `save` method is returning null. If I run from Eclipse as "Run As JUnit" it is working fine and test is passing. But the same test case with maven test is failing with null pointer because JpaRepository's `save` method is returning null. Any idea?

- Spring data - 1.8.0.RELEASE
- Hibernate - 4.3.8.Final
- Spring - 4.1.5.RELEASE
- Maven - 3.2.5
- Java8, Junit4

Note: I tried both `save` and `saveAndFlush` but with no luck.

**Service class**

```
Application appl=applicationRepository.saveAndFlush(application);//Returns null
```

**Repository class**

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Integer> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, 
           value = "select count (ap1.appn_id) cnt from appn ap1 where ...")
    List<BigInteger> countByCreatedTSLessThanEqual(String date);
}
```

Comment: are committing the `Transaction`?

Comment: Spring data internally has commit still i am commiting explicitly also.so i don't think commit is problem on further analysis even findOne method is also not returning data.

Comment: Can you share code for your test class?

Comment: I had this phenomenon in an unrelated matter. It turned out that an N-to-N relationship modeled by a List on the left side was making problems when inserting new objects on the right side because the left side List was updated and saved on two different places in the call stack (I think). Inserting right-side objects worked for a time, then nulls started to be returned. It's good to add appropriate logging statements at the critical places to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

We also encountered very similar problem. It was exactly as you described - **null** after save() or *saveAndFlush()* and **null** after *findOne()*.

In our case the reason was an aspect (Spring @Aspect) controlling data being saved via Spring JPA

```
@Around("execution(public !void org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.*(..))")
```

that filtered out the result. Make sure you have no aspects running around your calls to repository or adjust them if necessary.

As a workaround, we also managed to bypass the aspect by injecting entity manager directly and calling its methods.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

em.joinTransaction();
final Application savedAppl = em.merge(application);
```